# Is $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W = \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} | A_{11} \geq 0\}$ is $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$? Prove or disprove.

I know how to do it if it was a specific sized matrix, but I'm not sure how I would apply that to a general $n \times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with the subspace test? Check if $W$ is closed under matrix addition. Check if it is closed under scalar multiplication under $\mathbb{R}$. Is the zero matrix contained in $W$? Hint- the subspace test fails on scalar multiplication. Take $c = -1$ and $M \in W$. What is $cM$?

Comment: I am sorry, but where did the M come from?

Comment: I just picked an arbitrary matrix in $W$.

Comment: So if c was -1, then M would no longer be a 0 matrix?

Comment: If $M_{11} = 1$, what happens when you multiply $-1 * M$? You get $M_{11} = -1$. So is $-1M \in W$? Thus, what can you conclude about closure under scalar multiplication?

Comment: -1M is not an element of W because then M is no longer part of the O subspace?

Comment: $-1M \not \in W$, which implies that $W$ is not a subspace.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user136147 Consider accepting this answer. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Given $A\in W$ what is its additive inverse?

**Another hint:** If thinking geometrically is your thing, you can also consider the $n^2$-dimensional subspace whose vectors which consists of the entries of the matrices in $W$.

Comment: Comment, down voter?